# How to get mass assignment to utilize custom assignment methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

This is driving me totally nuts. I've got a custom setter and a custom getter for a phone number field:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :phone

  def phone=(p)
    p = p.to_s.gsub(/\D+/, '') 
    p = p[1..-1] if p.length == 11 && p[0] == '1' 
    write_attribute(:phone, p)
  end

  def phone(format=:display)
    case format
    when :display then return pretty_display(attributes['phone'])
    when :dialable then return dialable(attributes['phone'])
    else return attributes['phone']
  end
end
```

The methods in the case statement are just stubs for my actual implementation, so no need to get hung up on those. These get and set methods work well when I'm working with an object directly. For example:

```
person = Person.find(1)
person.phone = '(888) 123.4567'`)
puts person.phone            # => 888.123.4567
puts person.phone(:dialable) # => +18881234567
puts person.phone(:raw)      # => 8881234567
```

But when I do a mass assignment like `person.update_attributes( :phone => '(888) 123.4567' )`, the attribute gets set directly, bypassing my custom setter method and then the validation fails because it's not in raw form.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be much of a solution for this. I ended up giving up on it and just copying the code into a before_save filter. Seems heinous, but such is life....